# How to transfer photos from mac os to elementary os

Tags: software-installation, photos, macintosh, permissions, apple

I have breathed new live into my 2011 mac by installing elementary os. How do I transfer photos and music files from mac os to elementary os?
I have saved all my photos and music files to an external hard drive, but when I plug the external drive in and try to open the files on elementary os - I get a message saying that I don't have permission.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I imported my photos using the gear icon on the far top right, 'Import Photos'. It sorta worked... It seemed to only get the month of April's photos for each year. Also the program seems to be crashing as soon as it loads occasionally.

Keep good backups until all this is sorted out.

Comment: Thanks Gordon- much appreciated. I will give it a try.